# I send a remote host request to the slaves with the gui in the jmeter master, the output does not appear in the listener

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have 3 computers on the same network, I installed jmeter on all of them. Then I made the necessary settings and saved it. I started jmeter-server in 2 of them and jmeter in 1 of them. When I make a normal request with the Jmeter interface, I can see a listener, but when I make a request as a remote host, I can see that the request is gone from the cmd screen of that computer, but it is not visible in the listener in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

If slaves don't report sample results to master then there is something wrong with your [RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)

- JMeter master needs to be able to connect to slaves in order to transfer the test plan and start the test
- JMeter slaves need to be able to connect to the master in order to send the results back

Check [`jmeter.log`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) on master and `jmeter-server.log` files on slaves for any suspicious entries and amend your RMI configuration to allow bidirectional connectivity. You may need to open ports in your OS [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))

More information:

- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Comment: Hello, I have done all the operations in the articles. When I start the jmeter-server on the machine where I start jmeter, I can catch its requests. I have no problems, but I do not have a problem sending requests to other servers. It just doesn't show up in the listener on the screen.

I also see such error in jmeter-server.log

ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteTestListenerWrapper:  java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)

Comment: You need to point JMeter slave to the master by setting [`java.rmi.server.hostname` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) and passing master IP address or DNS hostname. You can add the line to system.properties like `java.rmi.server.hostname=your-master-ip-here` or pass it to JMeter slaves via `-D` command-line argument like `jmeter-server -D`java.rmi.server.hostname=your-master-ip-here`. More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: java.rmi.server.hostname=I also defined the ip address, but when I enter the master ip here, it gives an error at the start, is it correct to enter my own ip address?